# FunctionalTestCase in Mule - How do I load one flow before another?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mule

I have a Mule application, and I'm creating some unit tests including some Mock Web Services to test certain functionality. The Mock Web Services I'm creating using a test mule flow, so I'm registering an HTTP inbound endpoint.

When I run my test, I get a failure because one of my Spring objects fails to load due to the fact that it cannot reach my mock web service(The web service is loaded dynamically, so when doing the test, it resolves to localhost, otherwise it is usually an external service). I've made sure that when I do my `getConfigResources()` I load my mock web service flow file before I load my spring context beans, however I still get the error.

Is there a way to make Mule/Spring load my flow file and start up my `http:inbound-endpoint` before my Spring beans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting the `depends-on` attribute on your Spring bean to the name of the Mule flow, but I doubt it will work and I'm not convinced it's something desirable anyway.

Otherwise, the only thing I can think of is that you initialize the Spring bean factory yourself in a `@Before` method of your functional test case. This will give you an opportunity to pass the value of the dynamic port you're using with your mock HTTP inbound endpoint (assuming you do use a dynamic port, which is the recommended approach).

Comment: `@Setup` I'm unfamiliar with this, is that like an `@Before` in JUnit? Would there be a way to programmatically create my flow(with the mock service) so that I can guarantee it get's created before anything?

Comment: ROFL, sorry. Meant: `@Before`. Even if you create the flow programmatically, you need to first start Mule to be able to register it. When does your Spring bean perform its HTTP call: in an `initialize` / `@PostContruct` method?

Comment: During creation of the bean object. I calls the HTTP to get information which it caches on startup.

Comment: Do you mean in the constructor? If yes, that's not the best time for doing so. Better do that in an initialize method.

Comment: Sorry, This particular code is a factory class, and we're doing it in the factory create method.

Comment: That's possibly the root cause of your issue: the creation phase is too early to interact with anything else being created too (ie Mule flows in this case). Try postponing the HTTP call to the initialization phase, for example by creating a dedicated method and configuring it in the `init-method` of your Spring bean.